# Retrieve custom attribute parameter values?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

if i have created an attribute:

```
public class TableAttribute : Attribute {
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
}
```

which i apply to a few of my properties in a class

```
public class Person {
    [Table(HeaderText="F. Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}
```

in my view i have a list of people which i am displaying in a table.. how can i retrieve the value of HeaderText to use as my column headers? Something like...

```
<th><%:HeaderText%></th>
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In this case, you'd first retrieve the relevant `PropertyInfo`, then call [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.getcustomattributes.aspx) (passing in your attribute type). Cast the result to an array of your attribute type, then get at the `HeaderText` property as normal. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class TableAttribute : Attribute
{
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    [Table(HeaderText="F. Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Table(HeaderText="L. Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class Test 
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        foreach (var prop in typeof(Person).GetProperties())
        {
            var attrs = (TableAttribute[]) prop.GetCustomAttributes
                (typeof(TableAttribute), false);
            foreach (var attr in attrs)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", prop.Name, attr.HeaderText);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Jon Skeet's solution is good if you allow multiple attributes of the same type to be declared on a property.  (AllowMultiple = true)

ex:

```
[Table(HeaderText="F. Name 1")]
[Table(HeaderText="F. Name 2")]
[Table(HeaderText="F. Name 3")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

In your case, I would assume you only want one attribute allowed per property.  In which case, you can access the properties of the custom attribute via:

```
var tableAttribute= propertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute<TableAttribute>();
Console.Write(tableAttribute.HeaderText);
// Outputs "F. Name" when accessing FirstName
// Outputs "L. Name" when accessing LastName
```