# Serializing DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, reflection, serialization, data-annotations

I would like to store DataAnnotations inside a database. How can I retrieve a string representation of a DataAnnotation by reflection (or by other means)?

**Example**

```
public class Product
    {
        [DisplayName("Price")]
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^\$?\d+(\.(\d{2}))?$")]
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Result could be XML or JSON data as long as it is stringified.

Comment: Can you explain why you actually want this?

Comment: The reason is I'm building a CMS and I want to build "Content Types" from DTO classes.

Answer (score 1):

this is very similar to [retrieve-custom-attribute-parameter-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925686/retrieve-custom-attribute-parameter-values), i'd use it as a basis for your solution

Comment: The problem is I don't know the specific type of DataAnnotation so I can't access the properties as in this example (by casting the ValidationAttribute to a specific type).

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off writing your own validation provider, and then just store the validation rules in your database in a more convenient form. Parsing the strings to try to instantiate the attributes seems like more work than necessary. :)

Sample validation provider: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/enterprise-library-validation-example-for-aspnet-mvc-2.html

Comment: Thank you! Very pleased that you try helping me with this. The problem with the solution you provided is that I need it to work for all kind of DataAnnotations. I use custom attributes to store more than just validation rules. I can’t explain all the concept here but I need it to do exactly what I demonstrated in the example.

Comment: You can also write a model metadata provider for non-validation attributes.